# What is the application that creates this diamond effect?

Tags: special-effects

What is the application that creates this diamond effect?
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an "easy button" or to actually learn how to do this? I ask because there is probably no "easy button" - there is simply masking one image into another and the various ways of accomplishing this. The "easy button" would be off-topic for this site, as no one knows anyway (and really, you should ask Sara Shakeel). The actual how to for masking, however, is perfectly on topic. Let us know your image editor of choice and this can be reverse-engineered to teach you how to do it to other images.

Answer (score 4):

The application is Adobe Photoshop. See [this article on artist Sara Shakeel](https://www.designboom.com/art/sarah-shakeel-original-crystal-artist-12-08-2018/) where this is mentioned. In [another article](https://www.elledecor.com/it/best-of/a26995489/sara-shakeel-instagram-crystals-glitter/) she notes that a digital work like this "only takes a few hours".